# DisableWindow for short time

Tags: visual-c++

I have a C++ MMI and the user wants one of the CMMIButtons to be disabled for 15 seconds after he presses another one. I don't want to stop anything else, the whole thing has to continue. Is there a way to do this inside the button controls?

My first thought was to do this with a little thread, but I just wonder if there is a simpler way built into the C++ libraries somewhere.

Comment: MMI? CMMIButton? I don't understand that. Why not disable the button, start a timer (`SetTimer`) and when the timer fires enable the button again.

Comment: The program has to continue, not stop and wait for the button.

Comment: You don't answer my questions. And you did not look at my proposed solution (which does not stop the program).

Comment: Quite right, I could do it with a little timer. This (very large legacy) project has lots of timers running all over the place, and messages going back and forth. I think a thread is more elegant. Anyway, my question is, is there is an internal method in the button. It seems there isn't.